# Conditional npm install ARG in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, npm-install

I am trying to install node module packages from GitHub on the basis of the argument. I have tried but however I do not understand this solution completely. There is no error in the execution but I am sure it does not install the package. I run the container locally before deploy and getting the module not found an error

`Dokerfile` is like that.Can it be possible to keep each command in a new line?

```
FROM node:10

ENV HOME /usr/src/reach-live-api

ARG siteval

RUN mkdir -p $HOME
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
WORKDIR $HOME

COPY ./keys/reachlive_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo "Host bitbucket.org\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> /root/.ssh/config

COPY . $HOME
RUN npm install --silent --production

RUN if [ "$siteval" = "prod" ]; then \
    RUN npm install "reach-live-elasticsearch@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-elasticsearch-prod.git" \
    RUN npm install "reach-live-firebase@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-firebase-prod.git" \
    RUN npm install "reach-live-paypal@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-paypal-prod.git" \
    else \
    RUN npm install "reach-live-elasticsearch@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-elasticsearch.git" \
    RUN npm install "reach-live-firebase@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-firebase.git" \
    RUN npm install "reach-live-paypal@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-paypal.git"; \
    fi 

RUN npm prune --production

RUN rm -fr .npm
RUN rm -fr /root/.ssh
RUN rm -fr keys

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I use the following command to build

`docker build -t gcr.io/reachlive-123/api:25Apr2020 . --build-arg siteval=dev`

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: (If you run `docker history` on the built image, it will have your GitHub credentials there in plain text for anyone to see; you'd be better off trying to clone those dependencies outside of Docker.)

Comment: If you're not getting a shell error that it can't find a command `RUN` then this line isn't running at all.  Can you extend this to be a complete [mcve], including the entire `Dockerfile` and the `docker build` command you're running?

Comment: `docker build -t gcr.io/reachlive-123/api:25Apr2020 . --build-arg siteval=dev`, I use to create the build, I also update the question with complete docker file. Also, the git repo is private but I am using the token into docker file but I have not added the token into above question for security reason @DavidMaze

Comment: I am sure it is reaching at the step of npm install, but it considers that as a string instead of executing @DavidMaze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out the problem was in the

```
RUN if [ "$siteval" = "prod" ]; then \
 RUN npm install "reach-live-elasticsearch@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-elasticsearch-prod.git" \
 RUN npm install "reach-live-firebase@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-firebase-prod.git" \
 RUN npm install "reach-live-paypal@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-paypal-prod.git" \
 else \
 RUN npm install "reach-live-elasticsearch@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-elasticsearch.git" \
 RUN npm install "reach-live-firebase@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-firebase.git" \
 RUN npm install "reach-live-paypal@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-paypal.git"; \
 fi
```

I have changed it to and it works

```
RUN if [ "$arg" = "prod" ]; then \
 npm install reach-live-elasticsearch@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-elasticsearch-prod.git \
 reach-live-firebase@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-firebase-prod.git \ 
 reach-live-paypal@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-paypal-prod.git ; \
 else \ 
 npm install reach-live-elasticsearch@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-elasticsearch.git \ 
 reach-live-firebase@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-firebase.git \ 
 reach-live-paypal@git+https://github.com/lalitmohan001/reach-live-paypal.git; \
 fi
```

Thanks to **Pavittar Singh** for helping us figure this out!